# Need to keep a banner on one page but remove it from another

Tags: css

I'm super new to CSS

[I want to keep this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FqOZ.png)

[I want to remove as it looks weird.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju8jH.png)

They are the same element. when I use `display: none;` on WordPress, custom CSS deletes both of them. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to add different id to the elements? And then apply display:none; just to one of them